# How to change Qmenubar item hover effect color in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMenuBar in window, and background color is white, so when action is selected, or mouse is point at action, text color becomes white.
How can i change hover effect color? I tried to change from pallete by changing selected text color, but that doesn't worked

[image: No Action is selected]

[image: Mouse is pointing at Exit item]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 QMenuBar::setStyleSheet()
```

will do the trick.

You can fully customize the layout of your component. Be aware of using setStyleSheet means you'll completely override the style of the component with your stylesheet.

```
QString style = "QMenuBar::item:selected { background: white; } QMenuBar::item:pressed {  background: white; }"

menuBar.setStyleSheet(style);
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for, Thanks